# RCurl errors when fetching ssl endpoint

Tags: r, curl, ssl, https, rcurl

RCurl is giving me an `error:1411809D:SSL routines:SSL_CHECK_SERVERHELLO_TLSEXT:tls invalid ecpointformat list` when I try to connect via SSL to an https (not public, unfortunately) endpoint to fetch some JSON.

I've put `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE`, and I don't know how to adjust the cipher list to avoid ECC suites.

How do I fix this? It works fine in the browser.

Comment: The issue is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678695/in-python-3-2-i-can-open-and-read-an-https-web-page-with-http-client-but-urlli). Try setting `sslversion=3L` in your **RCurl** call with `ssl.verifypeer=TRUE`.

Comment: This fixed the ssl errors, thanks. There's a further issue with my calls in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051258/rcurl-getform-pass-http-headers that seems to be intermittently messing with ssl as well.

Comment: Okay, I've posted it as an answer then (and already responded to your other question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678695/in-python-3-2-i-can-open-and-read-an-https-web-page-with-http-client-but-urlli) for python. Setting `sslversion=3L` in your **RCurl** call with `ssl.verifypeer=TRUE` should resolve the problem.