# RCurl getForm pass http headers

Tags: r, http, curl, get, rcurl

Using RCurl's `getForm` function, which is the only nice way of passing in GET-parameters, I need to alter some http headers. In getURI, you just pass `httpheader = c(Whatever='whatever',...)` and it'll work. Unfortunately, that argument seems to be ignored by `getForm`.

How do I set the http headers in a getForm request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the confusing world of **RCurl**! You've discovered that its syntax makes no sense, which is not your fault.

In `getForm` you pass headers as the second argument (the `...`). See the *usage* section of `? getForm`:

```
getForm(uri, ..., .params = character(), .opts = list(), curl = getCurlHandle(),
         .encoding = integer(), binary = NA, .checkParams = TRUE)
```

The *arguments* section says:

> ...   the name-value pairs of parameters. Note that these are not the CURL options.

By contrast, the other workhorse function `getURL` says:

```
getURL(url, ..., .opts = list(),
        write = basicTextGatherer(.mapUnicode = .mapUnicode),
         curl = getCurlHandle(), async = length(url) > 1,
           .encoding = integer(), .mapUnicode = TRUE)
```

> ...   named values that are interpreted as CURL options governing the HTTP request.

Thus, when using `getForm`, you can just pass the headers as a list, but when using `getURL`, you need to specify them in a `httpheader` argument.

My general advice is therefore to always use `curlPerform` instead of any of the wrapper functions (like `getForm` or `getURL`), because then you'll always be using a consistent syntax.

Comment: Hmm, I took the ``...`` to be the GET-parameters, not the Headers (like Accept='application/json'). I'd just use curlPerform but I'm trying to avoid construct a URI by myself.

Comment: trying ``getForm(my_uri, Accept='application/json',.params=c(...),curl=ch)`` did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe you can only specify headers to `...` OR using `.params`, but not both, which you appear to be doing in that call.

Comment: A ha, you have to set ``.opts = list(httpheader = c(yourheadershere...)``