# Error:1411809D:SSL routines - When trying to make https call from inside R module in AzureML

Tags: r, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an experiment in AzureML which has a R module at its core. Additionally, I have some .RData files stored in Azure blob storage. The blob container is set as private (no anonymous access).

Now, I am trying to make a https call from inside the R script to the azure blob storage container in order to download some files. I am using the `httr` package's `GET()` function and properly set up the url, authentication etc...The code works in R on my local machine but the same code gives me the following error when called from inside the R module in the experiment

```
error:1411809D:SSL routines:SSL_CHECK_SERVERHELLO_TLSEXT:tls invalid ecpointformat list
```

Apparently this is an error from the underlying OpenSSL library (which got fixed a while ago). Some suggested workarounds I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046176/rcurl-errors-when-fetching-ssl-endpoint) were to set `sslversion = 3` and `ssl_verifypeer = 1`, or turn off verification `ssl_verifypeer = 0`. Both of these approaches returned the same error.

I am guessing that this has something to do with the internal Azure certificate / validation...? Or maybe I am missing or overseeing something?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: For all the people landing here - I didn't manage to completely resolve this but it does seem to be something related to the http`s` call. Trying the same thing with a http call seems to work (but makes the blob storage publicly available which turns into another problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, an answer came back from the support team, so I am going to post the relevant part as an answer here for anyone who lands here with the same problem.

"This is a known issue. The container (a sandbox technology known as "drawbridge" running on top of Azure PaaS VM) executing the Execute R module doesn't support outbound HTTPS traffic. Please try to switch to HTTP and that should work."

As well as that a solution is on the way :

"We are actively looking at how to fix this bug. "

Here is the original [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5866e16c-a145-481e-8764-f7c7823742b0/https-call-from-inside-r-module-possible-?forum=MachineLearning) as a reference.
hth